# Testcafe: How to typeText into hidden input for Spectrum color picker

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe, color-picker

I'm trying to send a color code to the [Spectrum color picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) input using `t.typeText(colorPickerInput)`, but this input is hidden and Testcafe throw an error. Based on documentaion option `{ visibilityCheck: false }` not works in case of `typeText()`

```html
<input id="ember949" class="spectrum-color-picker ember-view" style="display: none;">
```

Is any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe is intended to emulate real user behavior, so you cannot type into an input element with the "display: none" style. However, you can set the input value using the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism, which allows you to write any custom JS code.

Please see the following example:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const setInputValue = ClientFunction(() => {
    document.querySelector('input.spectrum-color-picker').value = '';
});

fixture `fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test('test', async t => {
    await setInputValue();
});
```